# How to get the correct XPath for Google Sheets' IMPORTXML on the Steam Workshop?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to set up a Google Sheets document to fetch mod update dates and times from the Steam workshop. How would I find the correct value for the ImportXML XPath field?

I've tried copying the XPath for the specific value I'm trying to fetch, but it doesn't seem to be working.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=843425103", //*[@id="mainContents"]/div[11]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/div[3]])
```

I expected the output of that to be `Sep 16, 2018 @ 5:24pm` Instead, it tells me I have a formula parsing error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

indeed your syntax is wrong. XPath needs to be quoted and double quotes within are not allowed so:

```
=IMPORTXML("https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=843425103", 
 "//*[@id='mainContents']")
```

example:

[image: 0]

```
=IMPORTxML("https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=843425103", 
 "//div[@class='detailsStatRight']")
```

[image: 0]